# Why does the audio have such poor quality when I playback screen captures?

Tags: windows-7, audio, screen-capture, microsoft-expression, camstudio

I can record a video and capture audio just fine, but when I play it back, there is something like white noise in the background, you can barely hear my voice, and it certainly isn't clear enough to understand what I am saying. I have posted the settings I am currently using below.  My recordings can either be .avi or .swf. I am currently using Windows 7, but I would like it to work on XP as well.

Obviously it would be nice to keep the file size as small as possible, but I really just want it to work right now.

[image: Audio Settings]

[image: Video Settings]

[image: Mic Settings]

Comment: You should first try to rule out whether Cam Studio is the problem. Can you voice record in another application without problems?

Comment: Good call. It was indeed working on other applications before, but apparently I accidentally hit the mute switch since the last time I used the mic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description it sounds as if you have the initial recording volume set too low.  Check your audio chain and record at as high a level as you can without distortion.

Comment: You were basically right. Actually there was a mute switch on the headset that was causing the problem.  Whoops.